# Laravel/PHP create an array from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

Hey guys I'm confused about how to create an array using specific keys from my pre-existing array.

**Laravel controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $content = Page::find(1)->content->toArray();

    return View::make('frontend.services', compact('content'));
}
```

`$content` is an array that looks similar to

```
array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        'id' => '1', 
        'page_id' => '1', 
        'name' => 'banner_heading', 
        'content' => 'some content', ), 
    1 => array ( 
        'id' => '2', 
        'page_id' => '1', 
        'name' => 'banner_text', 
        'content' => 'some other content' )
)
```

And I want it recreate this array to look like this

```
array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        'banner_heading' => 'some content' 
    ), 
    1 => array (  
        'banner_text' => 'some other content' 
    )
)
```

How can I move the keys `name` and `content` to equal their values as a single row in the array?

I greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: You could achieve this format directly from the query by using the `lists()` method instead of `toArray()`. `Page::find(1)->content->lists('content', 'name');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP >= 5.5.0:**

```
$result = array_column($content, 'content', 'name');
```

**PHP < 5.5.0:**

```
foreach($content as $key => $array) {
    $result[$key] = array($array['name'] => $array['content']);
}
```

Comment: Great answer @AbraCadaver! Thanks for including a way to make it work with the different versions. I have just implemented the one for PHP >= 5.5.0 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
$newContent = array();
foreach ($content as $record) {
    $newContent[] = array($record['name'] => $record['content']);
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel, but i believe that your solutions should be similar to this :

```
$newArray= array(); 
foreach($content as $key => $value)
{ 
   $newArray[] = $value["banner_heading"];
} 
return View::make('frontend.services', compact('newArray'));
```

Or at least it should be something similar with this.